# browser load error only with certain file path - internal server error 500

Tags: javascript, internal-server-error

I am getting internal server error 500 for only one js file and when I change the path of the file it works fine.  Here is the snippet from my index file:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/users.client.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/services/authentication.client.service.js"></script>
```

'users.client.module.js' doesn't load and gives 'internal server error' and the network tab in chrome shows it as 'text/html' type.  The other file 'authentication.client.service.js' loads fine. There are other js files as well and they all load fine. Here is the server error:

GET /users/users.client.module.js 500 6.716 ms - 1529

this is what network tab shows:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:3000
Request URL:`http://`127.0.0.1:3000`/users/users.client.module.js`
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)       Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1529
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 22 Nov 2014 20:02:07 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Powered-By:Express
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering
```

However when I put the file 'users.client.module.js' in the subfolder 'services', it loads fine.  Here is the example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/services/users.client.module.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/users/services/authentication.client.service.js"></script>
```

The above works fine.  I am confused as to why the browser doesn't load the file in the first case. I have tried it in both chrome as well as safari.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code from express.js file that shows server side routing for static resources

module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(session({
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    secret: config.sessionSecret
}));

// setting views/views engine
app.set('views', './app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// routes
require('../app/routes/index.server.routes.js')(app);
require('../app/routes/users.server.routes.js')(app);

// serving static file
app.use(express.static('./public'));

return app;
```

};

Comment: Don't you think it's a server-side issue, yet you don't show anything related to server configuration?

Comment: Ok, from the piece of log you've shown we know that the server is powered by NodeJS Express framework. Could you give us a chance of actually answering your question by showing the server-side routing code?

Comment: If it is of any help.  Interestingly when I change the name of the users folder to something else, such as staff, the file loads fine. example:  src="/staff/users.client.module.js"

Answer (score 1):

That's happening, because I bet you have a "/users/someparameter" route probably in the users.server.routes.js. So when you're requesting that js file it tries to go through the route. Probably the "someparameter" is an ID, so when requesting the users.client.module.js, it fails to parse the the parameter, since the filename is not an id.

You need to update the route or rename the "users" folder.